# PowerShell code running as scheduled task fails with Program Files folder

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run the following PowerShell command directly in a Scheduled Task.

```
Powershell.exe -command Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\Reports' -Force | Where-Object {($_.Name -like 'AB*.xml') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7))} | Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Program Files(x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\Reports\OldReports'
```

It fails because the scheduled task does not appear to be running with administrative privileges.

The task is configured as follows:

- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Specified user with local admin rights
- Run with highest privileges
- Action - Start a program
- Program = `powershell.exe`
- Parameters = `-command Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\Reports' -Force | Where-Object {($_.Name -like 'AB*.xml') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7))} | Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Program Files(x86)\CA\ARCserve Backup\Reports\OldReports'`

Permissions on folder have been changed to (authenticated users = full control)

If I run the command below in the same scheduled task, it completes successfully.

```
powershell.exe -command Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Reports' -Force | Where-Object {($_.Name -like 'AB*.xml') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7))} | Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Reports\OldReports'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the execution policy is too restricted for this account.
try to set the executionpolicy by adding `-executionpolicy unrestricted` in the parameters.
If that failed, it would help to see the log of the scheduler.

Comment: so the problem was a simple typo.
The second program files (x86) didnt have a space for some reason.

the rest of the config is working as expected.

Thanks for your help.